# Delta Flyer Transporter Capability

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-transporter

Why didn't the Delta Flyer have a transporter pad? We know Voyager is low on energy, so why use site-to-site transports regularly (site-to-site uses more energy due to requirement of two transporter cycles). If they use more energy, they're better off installing a pad.

I can understand emergency transporters being site-to-site to save space (for shuttlecraft,  etc) but the Flyer was designed as an away-mission vessel, which would require regular use of the transporter, why not install a pad like a Danune-class runabout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In-universe, it seems to be down to Lt. Paris' prejudices about what [the Flyer should be like](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/503.htm). He clearly intends it to be a "hot rod" with fancy spoilers and large pointless exhaust fins:

> **PARIS:** *Behold the Delta Flyer. **Ultra-aerodynamic contours**, retractable nacelles, parametallic hull plating, unimatrix shielding
>   based on Tuvok's brilliant design for the multispatial probe, and a
>   Borg-inspired weapons system.*

Adding a transporter *pad* would take up extra space and ruin the clean lines.

---

Note that in a [later episode](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/719.htm) it becomes apparent that the Flyer does have a transporter systems, but just no pad:

> **PARIS:** [in the Delta Flyer] *I'm getting a lock on it now.*
>   (Whumph!)
>   **PARIS:** *My transporters are offline.*

Comment: Your links appear to be broken...

Comment: @JonClements - How odd. They're fixed now. I hope that doesn't mean that all of the Chakoteya script links are broken too,

Comment: Sadly - running this [search](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A20774+url%3Achakoteya.net) seems to show that ds9 should now be DS9 and voyager should be Voyager - then I stopped looking... have fun :)

Comment: @JonClements - Oh holy crap.

Comment: Up to you - but it might be worth contacting the site's webmaster - they may have inadvertently invalidated a lot of links... seems they've (somehow) enforced casing when they probably may not have meant to...

Comment: @JonClements - That might be a good idea. It looks like there are some 450 answers that contain links to chakoteya, most of which are now invalid, in some cases multiply so

Comment: Easier than bump editing the posts and the site owner might want to know - appears they've got a FB page and an email on the main page

Comment: @JonClements - I don't do facebook and I don't use my personal email for site stuff. I'll raise it on Meta.